# jQuery String to Downloaded file

Tags: jquery, file, download

What is the best way to dump a long string (13,000+ characters) into a downloaded file with a name and an extension? Using jQuery, possibly ajax or php, if needed.

Thank you.

```
function output(){
$.ajax({
    dataType:"html",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
        content:$("#fileDump").contents().find('html').html(),
        fname:fileName
    },
    url:"filer.php",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data, status, error){
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Is the string generated client- or server-side?

Comment: You answered your own question jQuery, ajax and php (as possible serverside lang). I would ask why the server is not generating the 13,000+ characters though and why jQuery is, WYSIWYG? either way make sure to use POST not GET in your Ajax request

Comment: Yes, WYSIWYG. Nothing is saved Server side.

Comment: @anijam are you sure you specified POST and not GET ????

Comment: Yes. I just checked that. I must have forgotten that somewhere when I redid it. I have been going over and over this one piece for three days. I got the post to go through, I just don't see results from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP :

```
$content = "a long string";
file_put_contents($file, $content);
// force download
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
readfile($file);
```

Uses [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), [header](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

You can add a filename to the `Content-Disposition` if required :

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="a_text_file.txt');
```

Comment: It's not the php I'm having a problem with. It's the jquery/ajax. I get the response from the php, but it won't download.

Comment: Post your current code. Then we will have an idea of what your doung

Comment: Added the ajax. don't know what to do with it. I keep looking online and everyone says use an iframe, but I'm afraid I don't know what that means. It's already in a hidden iframe. I just want the user to get the download.

Comment: I did have a fully functional setup using window.location but, of course, that's a GET with limits. I also had it working without PhP at all, but since it didn't have a header...